# Google Distance Matrix API free limitations

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I'm writing a mobile app and considering using Distance Matrix API to get the driving distance from A -> B. Google writes the following under [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/#Limits):

```
Users of the free API:
    100 elements per query.
    100 elements per 10 seconds.
    2,500 elements per 24 hour period.
```

Are these 2,500 elements **per phone** or do **all phones** with my app share the same 2500 element limit?

Comment: It's based on total API requests using your key, regardless of which phone they come from.  The free API is really good only for testing - if you're using it in a commercial application you'll need a business key.

Comment: Okey. Thanks for the answer, really appreciated. Do you know if there's some other API i could call to get the fastest driving distance from A->B, with no limits on them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of use, not coding

Answer (score 2):

For distance matrix alternative, I recommend MapQuest Route Matrix
http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/#matrix

Answer (score 0):

All requests using your `key` will be restricted to that limit, doesn't matter where it comes from, the limit is bound to the key.

Here is [some good practices for protecting that key](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037?hl=en).