# Google Maps Distance Matrix API Usage Limits

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

According to the website: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits, it says:

Users of the standard API:

- 2,500 free elements per day
- 100 elements per query
- 100 elements per 10 seconds

What does the `elements` mean here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Comment: @duncan Noted. Do you know what elements mean here? If you know it please share with me, then I will delete this question. Thanks.

Comment: Not really. The page you link to says "Each query ... is limited by the number of allowed elements, where the number of origins times the number of destinations defines the number of elements."

Comment: did you end up figuring out what the limits mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Distance Matrix API free limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650422/google-distance-matrix-api-free-limitations)

Answer (score 1):

Each request sent to Google Maps Distance Matrix API is limited by the number of items allowed. The number of the request elements is obtained by multiplying the number of starting points by the number of destinations.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits

Answer (score 0):

Each query sent to the Distance Matrix API generates elements, where the number of origins times the number of destinations equals the number of elements.

Answer (score -1):

Elements mean the inputs which you give. For example you are getting distance between A to B, it is considered as 1 element. You give origins as A, B, C and destinations as D, E, F then it means 3 elements.

By the way, it is not a programming question and should not be asked in here.

Comment: Not correct: `the number of origins times the number of destinations equals the number of elements` according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-and-billing). So in your example, there would be 9 elements